# Passar múltiplos atributos para um Command Parameter no Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin-forms

Tenho uma função que é um List, nela tenho um botão e queria passar 2 parâmetros dessa lista pra esse botão para fazer o redirecionamento para a próxima tela, porém não sei como fazer isso, pois o CommandParameter só aceita um valor.

```
    public void MontaGrid(List<FormularioCompartilhado> forms)
    {
        foreach (var item in forms)
        {
            var frame = new Frame() { BorderColor = Color.Silver };
            var framePorcent = new Frame() { BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("eeeeee"), BorderColor = Color.Silver };
            var stacklayout = new StackLayout() { Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0), Padding = 10, BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("eeeeee") };
            var stacklayoutFramePorcent = new StackLayout() { };
            var grid = new Grid() { };

            var labelNome = new Label() { Text = "Nome: ", FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold, FontSize = 16 };
            var labelEmpresa = new Label() { Text = "Empresa: ", FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold, FontSize = 16 };
            var labelResult = new Label() { Text = "Resultado: ", FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold, FontSize = 16 };
            var labelResp = new Label() { Text = "Respondido: ", FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold, FontSize = 16 };

            var listaNome = new Label() { Text = $"{(item.Titulo != null ? item.Titulo : item.Hash )} ({ item.FormularioXEmpresa.Formulario.Nome })" };
            var listaEmpresa = new Label() { Text = item.FormularioXEmpresa.Empresas.Nome };
            var listaPorcentResult = new Label() { Text = item.Atingimento.ToString() + "%" };
            var listaPorcentResp = new Label() { Text = item.Respondido.ToString() + "%" };

            if (item.Permitirresponder == true)
            {
                var btnResponder = new Button()
                {
                    Text = "Responder",
                    TextColor = Color.White,
                    BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("17A2B8"),
                    CommandParameter = item.Hash, item.FormularioXEmpresa.Id;
                };
                btnResponder.Clicked += BtnRespondeForm_Clicked;

                grid.Children.Add(labelResp, 0, 0);
                grid.Children.Add(listaPorcentResp, 0, 1);
                grid.Children.Add(btnResponder, 0, 2);
            }

            framePorcent.Content = grid;
            stacklayoutFramePorcent.Children.Add(framePorcent);

            stacklayout.Children.Add(labelNome);
            stacklayout.Children.Add(listaNome);
            stacklayout.Children.Add(labelEmpresa);
            stacklayout.Children.Add(listaEmpresa);
            stacklayout.Children.Add(stacklayoutFramePorcent);

            frame.Content = stacklayout;
            BlocosLayout.Children.Add(frame);
        }
    }
```

No btnResponder quero passar no command para esse metodo do botao:

```
    private async void BtnRespondeForm_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var formularioCompartilhado = (FormularioCompartilhado)(sender as Button).CommandParameter;

        await Navigation.PushAsync(new ResponderFormularioPage(
            formularioCompartilhado.FormularioXEmpresa.Id,
            formularioCompartilhado.Hash, 
            IsOnline,true));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu fortemente recomendaria uma abordagem de [MVVM](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm) e [bindings](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-binding-basics) para fazer esse tipo de operação. Mas, para fins de exemplo, você pode passar o objeto inteiro no `CommandParameter`, assim como você está tentando recuperar no evento.

Veja:

```
var btnResponder = new Button()
    {
        Text = "Responder",
        TextColor = Color.White,
        BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("17A2B8"),
        CommandParameter = item
    };
```

Dentro do event handler você recupera as propriedades do objeto que tem interesse, como já está fazendo:

```
var formularioCompartilhado = (FormularioCompartilhado)(sender as Button).CommandParameter;
```